# Best way to set up a NSViewController initialized with initWithNibName:bundle:?

Tags: ios, macos, initialization, nsviewcontroller, awakefromnib

i have a subclass of NSViewController that loads its view from a nib (with initWithNibName:bundle: and it is the file's owner of that nib).

I need to do some initialization after the nib is loaded and i want my code to be the most compatible :

- In ios : There is the viewDidLoad method to do that
- In osx : In snow leopard, there is no method like viewDidLoad but awakeFromNib is called on the file's owner of the nib too

So my questions are :

1. Is awakeFromNib called also on the file's owner of the nib in Lion ?
2. If i use awakeFromNib, do i need to call [super awakeFromNib] ? (is NSViewController implements awakeFromNib ?)
3. If answer 1 is YES, is this a good solution ? :

> ```
> - (void)initAfterNibLoaded {
>    ...
> }
>
> - (void)viewDidLoad {
>    // Code for ios
>    [self initAfterNibLoaded];
> }
>
> - (void)awakeFromNib {
>    // Code for osx
>
>    // Not sure if necessary
>    [super awakeFromNib];
>
>    [self initAfterNibLoaded];
> }
> ```

If answer 1 is NO, is this a good solution ? :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   // Initialize after nib loaded
}

#ifndef TARGET_OS_IPHONE
- (void)loadView {
   // Call parent method
   [super loadView];

   // Simulate viewDidLoad method
   [self viewDidLoad];
}
#endif
```

Thank you

Comment: Since NSViewController is not present in UIKit, I'm not sure why you're generalizing across the platforms.

Comment: Yes but i want to do the less modification possible in the code if i need to port it to ios. Changing parent class from NSViewController to UIViewController is not a big deal but i prefer avoid having a lot of bug because some methods are called in ios and not in osx or vice-versa.

Comment: The answer is obviously jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I found:

1. Yes, `awakeFromNib`: is called also on the file's owner of the nib in Lion (and normally it's the same for the new Mountain Lion).
2. Starting on OSX 10.6, there is a category on `NSObject` that adds `awakeFromNib`, so it's safe to call `[super awakeFromNib]` from any subclass. For OSX before 10.6, we can use  `instancesRespondToSelector`: to know if the parent class implements `awakeFromNib`, the `NSView` or `NSObject` subclass must not call `[super awakeFromNib]`.